# Schwarzian derivative of inverse function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse

Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the Schwarzian derivative. I have to prove that if $\mathcal{D}f(x)$ exists $\forall x$ then $\mathcal{D}f^{-1}$ exists $\forall x\in D_{f^{-1}}$ then find a formula.

I tried changing the variable $x$ into $f^{-1}(x), f(x), f'(x), (f^{-1})'(x)$ and after they all got me nowhere I realised I wasn't doing math anymore but bruteforce. I have the feeling that I'll use $$(f^{-1})'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$ somewhere(which I did in some of my change of variables). Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried whether $\mathcal{D}(f\circ g)$ produces something helpful?

Comment: $$|\mathcal{D}f\circ g| \cdot g'^2+\mathcal{D}g$$ How can I exploit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the existence of $\mathcal{D}(f^{-1})$, note that the existence of $\mathcal{D}f$ implies $f'(x) \neq 0$, hence $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable as often as $f$ is, so sufficiently often for the Schwarzian derivative, and $(f^{-1})'(y) \neq 0$ always. So $\mathcal{D}(f^{-1})$ exists.

By the chain rule for Schwarzian derivatives, we have

$$0 = \mathcal{D}(\operatorname{id}) = \mathcal{D}(f\circ f^{-1}) = \bigl((\mathcal{D}f)\circ f^{-1}\bigr)\cdot \bigl((f^{-1})'\bigr)^2 + \mathcal{D}(f^{-1}).$$

Now it is a simple rearrangement to obtain the a formula for $\mathcal{D}(f^{-1})$.

Comment: What's a diffeomorphism? This is from Spivak's analysis book, and diffeomorphism isn't discussed at all(or I cannot guess the Greek term the translator used).

Comment: A diffeomorphism is a differentiable bijection such that the inverse is also differentiable.

Comment: Even though I can assume your answer is correct, I cannot accept it as I haven't learnt diffeomorphism, thus cannot prove something by using it's properties. Sorry for not clarifying my knowledge level. The answer to the second question is spot on though.

Comment: Even if you don't know the word, you certainly have the theorem that if $f\colon (a,b) \to (c,d)$ is a differentiable bijection with $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, then $f^{-1}\colon (c,d) \to (a,b)$ is differentiable? You used the formula for the derivative of $f^{-1}$ that is typically obtained in the proof of that theorem.

Comment: I have the theorem for a continuous differentiable injection $f$ and $f'(f^{-1}(x)) \neq 0$ then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable. That's where I obtained the formula for $(f^{-1})'(x)$.

Comment: @UserX Okay, that is in fact the slightly more general statement giving the differentiability of $f^{-1}$ in a specific point. An injection is a bijection from its domain to its range. And if $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ in its domain, then by that theorem, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$, so at every point $y$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$.